# Creating API for web app with CodeIgniter CSRF protection

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, restful-authentication

I have a web application built using CodeIgniter 2 , I have enabled CSRF protection in it. `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` My friend is creating mobile app for the same, so he needs API to communicate with Web App. I have created RESTful API in CI using [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/) . All the request made by mobile app are `POST` request. The problem I am facing is , since CSRF protection is enabled , and POST request made from mobile does not carry any "CSRF Token" so it is throwing `500 internal server error`. However if I **disable** CSRF protection everything is **working fine**. What is the correct way to implement it ? Shall I generate token on mobile itself ? Or shall I add exception to CSRF protection ? If so , then how can I do it ? because I don't want to disable CSRF protection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check out implementation of CSRF in codeigniter from **[net.tutsplus.com.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/protect-a-codeigniter-application-against-csrf/?search_index=1)**

I hope that will solve your problem.
if you implemented correctly than write this inside you config.php

```
if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) 
{
    if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/mypage') === FALSE)
    {
        $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
    } 
} 
else 
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need help in creating exception to DISABLE CSRF for some request, Generating CSRF is not a problem. Please read question carefully.

Comment: make sure you do not use same API for communication between your api file and web frontend. It'd expose those pages for CSRF attack.